# Does Samsung Galaxy S10 run Android version 12?

Tags: 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I'm reading about the Samsung Galaxy S10 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S10#Software). It says `The S10 range ships with Android 9.0 "Pie".` I made an app and a user is reporting a bug on it with the S10.

**What I Want To Know:** If the S10 ships with Android 9.0, does that mean that these phones will always have 9.0 only, or would they get updated to later versions of Android? If so, what's the highest version they run?

Comment: As mentioned on the Wikipedia link, "*An official list released by Samsung on December 2, 2020, further confirmed that all S10 models would be receiving the Android 11 upgrade with One UI 3.*", so they may be able to upgrade to Android 11. However, while [it's mentioned that newer Samsung devices will receive "at least three major Android updates"](https://9to5google.com/2020/08/05/samsung-android-updates-3-year-promise/), we can't really predict the future whether it will really receive Android 12 or not.

Comment: @AndrewT. Do you want to post this as a reply so I can accept?

Comment: Android 12 has not been released yet, therefore if an user has it installed this can only be a preview release or more likely an unlocked device with an Android 12 preview generic image.